# Find and save Mongoose for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an array of items and that need to be found and saved to MongoDB. Find from one model and get data from it and save via another model. `assets` is the array and `count` is the length of the array.

**Problem - Do I need to check out all records that are saved to DB or not?**

I need to get JSON response after complete pushing all records to the database.

```
    router.route('/move_qa')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        console.log('/move_qa');        
        console.log("*assets" + req.body.assets);
        var assets = req.body.assets;
        var count = req.body.count;
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var aBarcode = assets[i];
            console.log("$" + aBarcode);

                searchAndSave(aBarcode, function (resulttt) {
                    console.log("@"+resulttt);
                });
        }
        res.json({"result":true});
    });


    function searchAndSave(assetBarcode, callb) {

    pallet.findOne({assets: assetBarcode}, function (err, count) {

        if (err) {
            console.log("1 /pallet_details");
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log("2 /pallet_details");
            if (count == null) {
                console.log("3/pallet_details");
            } else {               

                var pbarcode = count.pBarcode;
                var date = new Date();

                var status = "NOT_COMPLETE";
                var newMoveToQA = new movetoqa({
                    keg_barcode: assetBarcode,
                    relevant_pbarcode: pbarcode,
                    move_date: date,
                    status: status
                });

                newMoveToQA.save(function (err) {
                    console.log("####******");
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("4");
                    } else {
                        console.log("5");
                        callb(true);

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: so what's the error you are getting here

Comment: you need to provide more information about your problem or else it will be difficult to help. What error you're facing?